# Getting an Easy Card in TPE airport?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, taiwan, taipei, tpe

Can I buy an Easy Card in TPE (and load it with money)? Can I use a credit card for that, or do I need to have NTD in cash to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, either from a convenience store within the airport (7Eleven, Family Mart, etc) or from the information desk at the Airport MRT station. The card itself costs NT$100 but comes with no balance, however the cashier can apply balance there and then once the card is purchased.

From memory, credit card wouldn't be an option from the MRT station as you'd need to purchase it from the information desk (they're cash only as far as I remember), but it should be an option from the convenience stores. There's a number of ATMs located around the airport should you need to take cash out.

There's some more information about where you can purchase an Easy Card at the [Easy Card website](https://www.easycard.com.tw/en/easycard?cls=1521769569&id=1521769904)

> These standard fare cards cost NT$100 each, exclusive of a deposit and balance.
>
> Four major convenience stores (7-Eleven, FamilyMart, Hi-Life, OK Mart), information centers at Taipei/Taoyuan/Kaohsiung Metro stations, and the EasyCard Corporation Customer Service Center

Comment: Do you happen to know the fare of the ride from TPE to Taipei Main Station if I pay by an EasyCard? There is a single ride ticket for 4.75 USD available through Klook, and I'm trying to figure out whether it's cheaper than using an EasyCard.

Comment: The standard fare between the airport and Taipei Main is NT$160 [according to this fare map](https://www.tymetro.com.tw/tymetro-new/en/_images/document/travel-guide/price.pdf), and there doesn't seem to be any distinction between Easy Card users and single journey token users, unlike the Taipei Metro. NT$160 is roughly $5.20 US, so your other method would appear to be slightly cheaper, though I've never heard of Klook before.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to bother you again, but would you mind pointing out where I can find the comparison of fares for the Taipei metro when paid by EasyCard vs. by one-time passes? I wasn't able to find that on the EasyCard website.

Comment: There is a 20% discount for using an Easy Card instead of a single-journey token. If you visit [this page](https://web.metro.taipei/e/TicketALLresult.asp) and select your starting station, it will list the fares to all other stations on the network. For example, a journey from Tamsui (R28) to Taipei Main Station (R10) would cost NT$50 for a single journey token but only NT$40 if you were to use your Easy Card.

Comment: Also worth noting that there's a minimum fare of NT$16, even if you tap into and out of the same station. I found that out when I needed to visit the toilet, but the closest one was inside an MRT station!